# enabling mirror api cant be done

Tags: java, google-glass, google-mirror-api

i am trying to enable mirror api and work on it as explained here https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/quickstart/java#creating_a_google_apis_console_project  but i cant see services tab and when i add it in the URL it shows "You don't have permissions to perform the action on the selected resource". can someone tell me how i can enable and start working on it

Answer (score 0):

Have you authorized using OAuth 2.0 credentials?

Please note from [**Authorizing Requests**](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/authorization):

> **Requests to the Google Mirror API must be authorized using OAuth 2.0 credentials**. You should use server-side flow when your application needs to access Google APIs on behalf of the user such as when the user is offline. This approach requires passing a one-time authorization code from your client to your server that is used to acquire an access and refresh tokens for your server.

Comment: yeah i have authorized OAuth credentials but i cant figure out how to use my client id and client password with eclipse it is showing 404 error when i launch localhost 8080 but eclipse was successfull in launching jetty server